# Adding one String and one int into the same spot in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a game where I count the ammount of clicks it takes to complete the game. I want to add the ammount of clicks and the player's name to an ArrayList. The goal is to make it possible to arrange the scores like some kind of high score table.

The questions is, how do I make it so that both the name of hte player and the ammount of clicks are stored in the same spot so that when I arrange the high scores the players name will stay connected to the ammount of clicks?

Comment: Java is an **Object** Oriented language.

Comment: Use array of structures (would be classes in Java)

Comment: Is click count is considered as score of the player?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a class that contains required information in it.

```
class PlayerClicks{
    private String palyerName;
    private int clicksCount;

    // add more data if needed
    // getter & setter
}
```

now create a `ArrayList` of type `PlayerClicks` object such as

```
List<PlayerClicks> list = new ArrayList<PlayerClicks>();
```

Now come to your question : *The goal is to make it possible to arrange the scores like some kind of high score table.*

Simply create a `Map<Integer,List<PlayerClicks>>` that contains `List<PlayerClicks>` as value and score as key such as

```
Map<Integer,List<PlayerClicks>> highScores = new TreeMap<Integer,List<PlayerClicks>>();
```

`TreeMap` is by default sorted by score as per key. Now get all the list of players having same score.

Comment: If two players have the same score ?, I think its better to keep may be playername (even playername can be same) as key

Comment: But OP want to sort based on score. Its' possible and there is no problem if both the players having same score because they are stored in the list.

Comment: Still score cannot be key, but without knowing detailed requirement we cannot suggest much.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList` can store one element in each spot. So if you must use an ArrayList, then you can define a Score object to store in the list:

```
public class Score {

    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Score(String n, int s) {
        name = n;
        score = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

...and add Score objects in the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Score> highScores = new ArrayList<Score>();
highScores.add( new Score("Tom",22) );
highScores.add( new Score("Dick",17) );
highScores.add( new Score("Harry",19) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would maintain a list of objects containing both name and the number of clicks. To make it work like a high score table, let the class of the object implement comparable and then call Collections.sort() on the list. Here is an example of how that would work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class HighScoreTest {

    static class Player implements Comparable<Player>{
        private String name;
        private int clicks;

        public Player(String name, int clicks){ this.name = name; this.clicks = clicks; }
        public String getName(){ return name; }
        public int getClicks(){ return clicks; }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Player o) {
            return Integer.compare(o.clicks, clicks);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

        players.add(new Player("Mark", 3));
        players.add(new Player("Jane", 5));
        players.add(new Player("Bert", 4));

        Collections.sort(players);

        for (Player p : players) {
            System.out.println(p.getName() + " has " + p.getClicks() + " clicks!"); 
        }
    }

}
```

This prints:
Jane has 5 clicks!
Bert has 4 clicks!
Mark has 3 clicks!
... which behaves like a high score and is easy to work with, no need for maps. It will also support players having the same amount of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a `Map<String, Integer>` where the string is the name of the player and the Integer is the score.

Then, you can put all that into a list.

Comment: What OP is asking? There are three things that is involved in the question playerName, clicksCount and score.

Comment: I think the OP says that the clicks are the score.

Comment: It might be possible. Let's confirm from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Map<String, Integer>` where the keys will be the user names, and the values will be the click counts.

An example:

```
    private Map<String, Integer> scores = new HashMap<>();

    private incrementScore(String userName) {
        Integer newScore = scores.get(userName) + 1;
        scores.put(userName, newScore);
    }
```